# My script Deallocated vm from powershell started throwing an error from Jule, How to reWrite?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I use PowerShell Script to the start azure automation which deallocated vm on name:

```
$clientID = "..."
$key = "..."

$SecurePassword = $key | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $clientID, $SecurePassword

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant "..." -ServicePrincipal

$params = @{"RESOURCEGROUPNAME" = "..."; "VMNAME" = $env:computername}
    Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -ResourceGroupName "..." -AutomationAccountName "..." -Name "StopAzureV2Vm" -Parameters $params
```

but from Jule/22 command Add-AzureRmAccount ... started throw error:

*Add-AzureRmAccount : AADSTS1002016: You are using TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the
security posture of Azure AD. Your TenantID is: 7441e116-ef50-4bf6-a98f-1fa0671ccfb5. Please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2161187 and conduct needed actions to remediate the issue. For further questions, please
contact your administrator.*

please help rewrite my code for new Requirements?

Comment: you  can't add/update the registry key since it runs on some automation server. May be try adding this line `$TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Ssl3 , Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below ways to fix the issue:

1. ***Add-AzureRmAccount*** commands are deprecated. Try to use **[Add-AzureAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/add-azureaccount?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)** to avoid this error.
2. Disable the TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1 Protocols. Enable the Protocol**[TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement#powershell-script-to-enable-tls-12)** in client so that we can avoid this issue.
3. You can include below script to fix your issue

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
```

Refer the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem) to solve the TLS 1.0 issues